# Почему размер окна браузера на мобильном устройстве, отличается от разрешения экрана телефона

Tags: html, css

К примеру взять Iphone X. Разрешение экрана 2436×1125. Но если в хроме открыть панель инструментов, и выбрать там режим отображения того же Iphone X, то видим совсем другие цифры. 375х812. Аналогично с любыми другими мобильными устройствами

Comment: Потому что CSS-пиксель не равен физическому пикселю. Если бы был равен, было бы слишком мелко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современных смартфонах высокая плотность пикселей экрана. Это сделано для улучшения качества изображения. Чем больше ppi (англ. pixels per inch - пикселей на дюйм), тем меньше человеческий глаз может различить пиксель, тем более четким выглядит изображение. Например, в том же Iphone X она составляет 458 ppi.

Соответственно, это привело к тому, что количество экранных пикселей уже не соответствует пикселю изображения, а соотносится как 2:1, 3:1 и даже 4:1. В экране Iphone X тройная плотность пикселей (2436 / 812 = 3, 1125 / 375 = 3).